# Существует ли эквивалент java.template в C#?

Tags: java, c#

Вопрос в следующем, в Java есть файлы шаблонов, по которым в последствии можно создавать новые файлы (подробнее тут https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-and-code-templates.html) есть ли что нибудь похожее на платформе.NET?

Comment: ```````t4```````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует и название похожее - T4 Text Templates или просто T4.

Документация:

- [Code Generation and T4 Text Templates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019)
- [Создание кода и текстовые шаблоны T4](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019)